# gtalk stopped support for xmpp. What is alternate solution to integrate gmail chat in android app?

Tags: android, smack, google-talk

Recently i came to know that google stopped support for xmpp for its gtalk product. And gtalk is replaced by hangouts. I want to integrate gmail chat in my android app. what is alternative way?

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit late, but you still can use xmpp to send and receive messages, suscribe request, user composing .. You can use it with google hangouts and google talk, the only think is that hangouts only support 1v1 chat.
One difference between hangouts and talk is also the sid used, if you add someone in your contact list through hangouts his sid will be an adress ending with .public.talk.google.com.
You can avoid that by sending the suscrbube request through xmpp protocol or by using google talk in gmail. Then you will still be able to communicate through hangouts.
One last thing, you have tu use a google account to talk to another google account.